Can Batch Encode and Bootstrapping Be Used Together
I have referenced some documents stating that "To implement bootstrapping, the plaintext modulus 
needs to be chosen as a prime power." Meanwhile, the SEAL library documentation on Batch Encoding mentions that "Batching only works when the plaintext modulus  is chosen to be a prime number and congruent to 1 (mod 2n).".However, in this paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/462.pdf, I noticed that the author used both Batch Encoding and Bootstrapping, while choosing
 as a prime power. Can someone help me clarify this?

I believe there is a confusion here between what batching itself requires and what SEAL's implementation of batching requires.
To use batching, everything you need is the plaintext space
$R_t = \mathbb{Z}_t[X]/\langle \Phi_m(X) \rangle$
to be isomorphic to a direct product of rings, that is,
$$
R_t \simeq \mathbb{Z}_t[X]/\langle f_1(X) \rangle \times \mathbb{Z}_t[X]/\langle f_2(X) \rangle \times ... \times \mathbb{Z}_t[X]/\langle f_s(X) \rangle
$$
which is the same as saying that you have to choose your plaintext modulus $t$ such that $\Phi_m(X) \equiv f_1(X) \cdot f_2(X) \cdot f_s(X) \pmod t$.
In this case, we say that we have $s$ slots.
Now, the first simplification that SEAL does is to always use $m$ as a power of two, which means that $\Phi_m(X) = X^n + 1$, where $n = 2^k$.
But, still, it would be possible to choose $t$ more or less as you want. However, must probably to simplify the implementation, they restrict their code to $t$ such that $t \equiv 1 \pmod{2n}$. That is because it implies $s = n$ (so maximizing the number of slots) and the degree of each $f_i$ to be 1, in other words, the plaintext space becomes $\mathbb{Z}_t^{n}$. This simplifies the encoding and decoding functions.
Finally, about the apparent inconsistency between the paper's claims and SEAL library, I think the authors just implemented their experiments for the paper on top of SEAL, by changing/completing SEAL implementation. An evidence of that is the fact that SEAL does not implement FV bootstrapping (as far as I remember).

A prime power is just a positive integer that has only 1 unique factors other than 1. For example:
$27 = 3^3, 125=5^3$ etc.
The requirement from the SEAL library means the exponent must be 1.

Ah, I see. But in my attached paper, the author chooses parameter t as 127^3, which does not meet the requirement of SEAL. He uses both bootstrapping that requires t is p^r is a prime power with r > 1 (specifically, in this case, p is 127 and r is 3) and batch encode that requires t is a prime number in SEAL.  Because this paper was published a long time ago and I couldn't find any public code, so I'm not very clear about this issue
